# python linux timestamp to date time and reverse

Tags: python, python-3.3

i would like to know how to convert datetime `Wed Apr 24 19:25:06 2013 GMT` into Linux timestamp `1366831506000` (13 digits)] and reverse using python.

for example:

```
Wed Apr 24 19:25:06 2013 GMT
```

to

```
1366831506000
```

and from

```
1366831506000
```

to

```
Wed Apr 24 19:25:06 2013 GMT
```

Comment: `import time` `str(time.strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y GMT", time.gmtime()))` to get `Wed Apr 24 19:25:06 2013 GMT` from the program directly

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From string to timestamp, use [`time.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime), passing the resulting `struct_time` tuple to [`time.mktime()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.mktime); your timestamp uses *milliseconds*, not the UNIX seconds-as-floating-point value, so you need to multiply by 1000:

```
import time

datestr = "Wed Apr 24 19:25:06 2013 GMT"
time.mktime(time.strptime(datestr, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z")) * 1000
```

In the other direction, use [`time.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime), passing in a `struct_time` tuple created by [`time.gmtime()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.gmtime), dividing the timestamp by 1000 first:

```
timestamp = 1366831506000
time.strftime("%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", time.gmtime(timestamp / 1000.0))
```

Demo:

```
>>> datestr = "Wed Apr 24 19:25:06 2013 GMT"
>>> time.mktime(time.strptime(datestr, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z")) * 1000
1366827906000.0
>>> timestamp = 1366831506000
>>> time.strftime("%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", time.gmtime(timestamp / 1000.0))
'Wed 24 Apr 2013 19:25:06 GMT'
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help Martijn Pieters

Comment: hi i am really sorry i was not clear with my question before, i am trying to convert 'datestr = "Wed Apr 24 19:25:06 2013 +7200"' [+7200 = offset in seconds for GMT+2 (Europe/Berlin Time Zone)] into linux timestamp but this didn't work with the demo you have given above

Comment: @sanjayanravi: No, to handle timezones you need an external library. Use [`python-dateutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil).

Comment: @sanjayanravi: `+7200` is a *weird* offset, expressed in seconds instead of hours and minutes. `+0200` would be the correct UTC offset.

Comment: python program is not accepting  hours and minutes +0200 for GMT+2 it is accepting only the Epoch (reference date) format according to the following link http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/timezones.php?epoch=1366888990

Comment: You could also parse the date minus the `+7200` offset with `datetime.datetime.strptime`, parse the `+7200` part manually into an integer, then use [`dateutil.tz.tzoffset`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-8bf499d888b70bc300c6c8820dc123326197c00f) to turn that into a timezone. *Then* turn the `datetime.datetime` object into a timestamp.

Comment: @sanjayanravi: The other way around, timestamp to datetime string with timezone is not possible without separately specifying what timezone should be used.

Comment: Will it assume the date is today if not given in the input string?

Comment: Never mind, it assumes Jan 1 1900 on my raspberry pi.